# Handler postDelayed only executes 1 once inside a loop

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I'm new in android programming. I have a problem in postDelayed wherein the delay only execute once inside a loop even if the value that I want to call is more than 1.

here is my code

```
protected void managerOfSound() {

    int size = tempq.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < tempq.size(); i++) {
        String u =tempq.get(i);



    //WHOLE
        if (u.equals("a4")){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a4);


      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run() {  
                   mp.start();
               }            
            },2000);

      }else if (u.equals("b4")){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b4);

       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run() {  
                   mp.start();
               }            
            },2000);
       }
   }
}
```

For example

before playing the mediaplayer, i want a delay of 2 seconds and another 2 seconds so on and so forth depending on how many values i want to call... like for example the values are a4, a4 and a4. i want a delay of 2 seconds everytime the values are called. Is there anyone who can help mo with this? thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What happens is the loop gets executed at once almost instantaneously. All sounds are queued right away. Changing `}, 2000` to `}, (i+1) * 2000` should fix it (saying delay the first sound by 2 seconds, the second sound by 4 seconds etc.).

Comment: thanks. i tried it but its not working.

Comment: You should use [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead of `MediaPlayer` for playing short sounds. Please read this carefully, I can already tell you already you won't be calling `new SoundPool` more than once.

Answer (score 4):

well your problem is that you are running `postDelayed`from inside a for loop. you do run the handler n times BUT simultaneously. you start all of them at the same time (because it takes less than a milli to finish the foor loop). you should 
put a `counter` on the amount of time. something like

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {  
               mp.start();
           }            
        },countr += 2000);
```

Comment: it's not working because the way you are using MediaPlayer...you have plenty of errors in your code...first try my code with some dummy int variable instead of mp and you will be able to see that the loop is functioning like you want...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample of a runnable with delay timer.

```
public Runnable timedTask = new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // type code here which will loop with the given delay



        //if you want to end the runnable type this in the condition
        if(condition) {

        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        return;

         }



        //delay for the runnable
        handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 2000);
    }
};
```

and you can call this method from anywhere by typing:

```
handler.post(timedTask);
```

hope it helps!